# React modules installation fails

Tags: javascript, reactjs, npm, yarnpkg

I'm trying to install `sass-loader` and `node-sass` via both `yarn` and `npm` , but getting the same errors .

I tried using one of these:

```
yarn add sass-loader@6.0.6 node-sass@4.5.3
npm install sass-loader@6.0.6 node-sass@4.5.3
```

But both produce similar errors. This is the response from yarn :

**EDIT:** I'm using windows. After setting the path of python this is the response I get:

```
[3/4] Linking dependencies...
warning " > react-modal@2.2.2" has incorrect peer dependency "react@^0.14.0 || ^
15.0.0".
warning " > react-modal@2.2.2" has incorrect peer dependency "react-dom@^0.14.0
|| ^15.0.0".
[4/4] Building fresh packages...
[-/2] ? waiting...
error C:\Users\sagil\Desktop\ReactTutorial\indecision-app\node_modules\node-sass
: Command failed.
Exit code: 1
Command: node scripts/build.js
Arguments:
Directory: C:\Users\sagil\Desktop\ReactTutorial\indecision-app\node_modules\node
-sass
Output:
Building: C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe C:\Users\sagil\Desktop\ReactTutorial\
indecision-app\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js rebuild --verbose --libsass
_ext= --libsass_cflags= --libsass_ldflags= --libsass_library=
gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
gyp verb cli [ 'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe',
gyp verb cli   'C:\\Users\\sagil\\Desktop\\ReactTutorial\\indecision-app\\node_m
odules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js',
gyp verb cli   'rebuild',
gyp verb cli   '--verbose',
gyp verb cli   '--libsass_ext=',
gyp verb cli   '--libsass_cflags=',
gyp verb cli   '--libsass_ldflags=',
gyp verb cli   '--libsass_library=' ]
gyp info using node-gyp@3.8.0
gyp info using node@10.7.0 | win32 | x64
gyp verb command rebuild []
gyp verb command clean []
gyp verb clean removing "build" directory
gyp verb command configure []
gyp verb check python checking for Python executable "python2" in the PATH
gyp verb `which` failed Error: not found: python2
gyp verb `which` failed     at getNotFoundError (C:\Users\sagil\Desktop\ReactTut
orial\indecision-app\node_modules\which\which.js:13:12)
gyp verb `which` failed     at F (C:\Users\sagil\Desktop\ReactTutorial\indecisio
n-app\node_modules\which\which.js:68:19)
gyp verb `which` failed     at E (C:\Users\sagil\Desktop\ReactTutorial\indecisio
n-app\node_modules\which\which.js:80:29)
gyp verb `which` failed     at C:\Users\sagil\Desktop\ReactTutorial\indecision-a
pp\node_modules\which\which.js:89:16
gyp verb `which` failed     at C:\Users\sagil\Desktop\ReactTutorial\indecision-a
pp\node_modules\isexe\index.js:42:5
gyp verb `which` failed     at C:\Users\sagil\Desktop\ReactTutorial\indecision-a
pp\node_modules\isexe\windows.js:36:5
gyp verb `which` failed     at FSReqWrap.oncomplete (fs.js:158:21)
gyp verb `which` failed  python2 { Error: not found: python2
gyp verb `which` failed     at getNotFoundError (C:\Users\sagil\Desktop\ReactTut
orial\indecision-app\node_modules\which\which.js:13:12)
gyp verb `which` failed     at F (C:\Users\sagil\Desktop\ReactTutorial\indecisio
n-app\node_modules\which\which.js:68:19)
gyp verb `which` failed     at E (C:\Users\sagil\Desktop\ReactTutorial\indecisio
n-app\node_modules\which\which.js:80:29)
gyp verb `which` failed     at C:\Users\sagil\Desktop\ReactTutorial\indecision-a
pp\node_modules\which\which.js:89:16
gyp verb `which` failed     at C:\Users\sagil\Desktop\ReactTutorial\indecision-a
pp\node_modules\isexe\index.js:42:5
gyp verb `which` failed     at C:\Users\sagil\Desktop\ReactTutorial\indecision-a
pp\node_modules\isexe\windows.js:36:5
gyp verb `which` failed     at FSReqWrap.oncomplete (fs.js:158:21)
gyp verb `which` failed   stack:
gyp verb `which` failed    'Error: not found: python2\n    at getNotFoundError (
C:\\Users\\sagil\\Desktop\\ReactTutorial\\indecision-app\\node_modules\\which\\w
hich.js:13:12)\n    at F (C:\\Users\\sagil\\Desktop\\ReactTutorial\\indecision-a
pp\\node_modules\\which\\which.js:68:19)\n    at E (C:\\Users\\sagil\\Desktop\\R
eactTutorial\\indecision-app\\node_modules\\which\\which.js:80:29)\n    at C:\\U
sers\\sagil\\Desktop\\ReactTutorial\\indecision-app\\node_modules\\which\\which.
js:89:16\n    at C:\\Users\\sagil\\Desktop\\ReactTutorial\\indecision-app\\node_
modules\\isexe\\index.js:42:5\n    at C:\\Users\\sagil\\Desktop\\ReactTutorial\\
indecision-app\\node_modules\\isexe\\windows.js:36:5\n    at FSReqWrap.oncomplet
e (fs.js:158:21)',
gyp verb `which` failed   code: 'ENOENT' }
gyp verb check python checking for Python executable "python" in the PATH
gyp verb `which` succeeded python C:\Python27\python.EXE
gyp verb check python version `C:\Python27\python.EXE -c "import sys; print "2.7
.13
gyp verb check python version .%s.%s" % sys.version_info[:3];"` returned: %j
gyp verb get node dir no --target version specified, falling back to host node v
ersion: 10.7.0
gyp verb command install [ '10.7.0' ]
gyp verb install input version string "10.7.0"
gyp verb install installing version: 10.7.0
gyp verb install --ensure was passed, so won't reinstall if already installed
gyp verb install version not already installed, continuing with install 10.7.0
gyp verb ensuring nodedir is created C:\Users\sagil\.node-gyp\10.7.0
gyp verb created nodedir C:\Users\sagil\.node-gyp\10.7.0
gyp http GET https://nodejs.org/download/release/v10.7.0/node-v10.7.0-headers.ta
r.gz
gyp WARN install got an error, rolling back install
gyp verb command remove [ '10.7.0' ]
gyp verb remove using node-gyp dir: C:\Users\sagil\.node-gyp
gyp verb remove removing target version: 10.7.0
gyp verb remove removing development files for version: 10.7.0
gyp ERR! configure error
gyp ERR! stack Error: connect ETIMEDOUT 104.20.22.46:443
gyp ERR! stack     at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1163:1
4)
gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 6.1.7601
gyp ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Users\\sagil\\Deskto
p\\ReactTutorial\\indecision-app\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js" "reb
uild" "--verbose" "--libsass_ext=" "--libsass_cflags=" "--libsass_ldflags=" "--l
ibsass_library="
gyp ERR! cwd C:\Users\sagil\Desktop\ReactTutorial\indecision-app\node_modules\no
de-sass
gyp ERR! node -v v10.7.0
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.8.0
gyp ERR! not ok
Build failed with error code: 1
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/add for documentation about this comm
```

I've tried downloading python 2.7 as stated in one of the errors. But the errors remains the same. I am stuck on this for 3 hours and would appreciate some help.

Could it be some permissions stuff? I don't understand why this is happening as I'm simply following a basic tutorial step by step .

Comment: Yes I am @HyyanAboFakher

Comment: _Can't find Python executable "python", you can set the PYT
HON env variable._
You should install python and **put** path to bin folder to PATH variable.

Comment: @see https://superuser.com/questions/143119/how-do-i-add-python-to-the-windows-path

Comment: Why do the versions need to be specific? I'm pretty sure that installing the latest version of both of these will solve this issue.

Comment: @NonameSL already tried that, didn't help. And I'm just following a tutorial so I wanna be consistent with it .

Comment: @Анатолий Where do I do that ? (I already installed python)

Comment: @Yossi see the link I have shared to add Python to your path

Comment: @HyyanAboFakher Done that, waiting for something to finish and I'll test to see if it works . I'll update in a few minutes

Comment: @HyyanAboFakher The error changed a bit, but looks similar. I'll update the question

Comment: @HyyanAboFakher Can you take a look ?

Comment: @Yossi the python problem is solved , you need to install [Visual Studio Build Tools](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/thank-you-downloading-visual-studio/?sku=BuildTools)

Answer (score 0):

It is a quite a common case that `node-gyp` build fails on windows.
to make the build pass, follow the steps described in the [official documentation](https://github.com/nodejs/node-gyp#on-windows)

The easiest way to make this work is by installing [`windows-build-tools`](https://github.com/felixrieseberg/windows-build-tools) using `npm` or `yarn`

```
npm install --global --production windows-build-tools
```

then try again to install `node-sass` and `sass-loader`

The problem can be solved too by using [Bash on Ubuntu on windows](https://www.howtogeek.com/249966/how-to-install-and-use-the-linux-bash-shell-on-windows-10/)

Comment: I'll ask for permissions and report back on the status. Thanks for the help .

Comment: Sorry for the delay. Apperently it was permissions problem, specific ports that are blocked or w/e , and that's why some of the downloads worked and some didn't . We've added the requiered permissions. Thanks for the help, upvoted :)

Answer (score 0):

I think the error clearly states that python is not added in your environment variables or it is not even installed on the system. please resolve the python dependency and try again.

```
gyp verb check python checking for Python executable "python2" in the PATH
```

Comment: Can you check if it is in your environment variables?